# django href url with parameter throwing error

Tags: python, django

I have the following setup for a simple `href` download page:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^kpis/$', InternalKPIView.as_view(), name='internal_kpis'),
    url(r'^tenants/$', TenantListView.as_view(), name='tenant-list'),
    url(r'^tenants/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', TenantStatsView.as_view(), name='tenant-stats'),
    url(r'^fileformaterror/$', FileFormatErrorView.as_view(), name='file-format-error'),
    url(r'^fileformaterror/download/(?P<s3_key>.*)$', FileFormatErrorDownloadView.as_view(), name='file-format-error-download'),   
]
```

template.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'file-format-error-download' s3_key=file.s3_key %}" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

views.py:

```
class FileFormatErrorDownloadView(View):
    def get(self, request, s3_key):
        pass
```

But when executing I get the following error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'file-format-error-download' not found. 'file-format-error-download' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Tree output of the related files:

```
$ tree -I "*.pyc|__pycache__"
.
├── apps.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   └── __init__.py
├── templates
│   └── backoffice
│    ├── file_format_error.html
│    └── internal_kpis.html
├── urls.py
└── views.py

3 directories, 7 files
```

Comment: Why do you need .* in (?P<s3_key>.*)?

Comment: You should show the full error message. And the full urls.py; is that included via a namespace?

Comment: @Gnoliz It is supposed to match anything, I guess it could be omitted as well

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the full urlpatterns now

Comment: Could you please verify that replacing `href` value with `{% url 'file-format-error' %}` works fine?

Comment: @ErnestTen no it does not, I get the same error

Comment: @wasp256 Do you have your application listed in [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS)?

Comment: @wasp256 Also, could you please show the whole project structure? I'm pretty sure the problem is in your main `urls.py` (and the one you are showing seems to belong to one of the applications). My guess is that you either not including URLs of your application properly or adding a namespace to them.

Comment: @ErnestTen Yes it it listed under `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @ErnestTen That was it!! There was a namespace defined in another urls.py! Can you please formulate it as an answer then I can accept it

Comment: @wasp256 Sure thing. I'm glad we found the source of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've provided it seems like the `urls.py` you are showing belongs to one of the applications within the project. My guess is that URLs of that application are either not included properly or included with a namespace.

Comment: Yes the this particular `urls.py` was imported in another `urls.py` which added a namespace to it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

why not use django2.0+? then code may as below:

urls.py

```
path('fileformaterror/download/<s3_key>/', FileFormatErrorDownloadView.as_view(), name='file-format-error-download')
```

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'file-format-error-download' file.s3_key %}" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
class FileFormatErrorDownloadView(View):
    def get(self, request, s3_key):
        return HttpResponse('success')
```

Comment: The application is running Django 1.11.9, I can't just simply switch to 2.0

Comment: I added the tree output

Comment: That is A LOT of output that I'm not willing to put on a public forum tbh, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I want to see the content of `urls.py` at the same directory of `wsgi.py`